# copy multiple csv files to postgresql tables in one psql copy call

Tags: postgresql, psql

loading a csv file to my postgresql db table using psql utility copy as below;

```
psql -h $host -p $port -d $db -U $username -c "\copy \"$schema\".\"$table\" from '$datafile' with delimiter as ',' csv"
```

this works great. However, I need to load many files at the same time. I can run above psql copy command in parallel fashion. Since each call starts a new process (my app is dotnet core 2.1 and is running on openshift), increasing the number of file also increases the memory and CPU. Process time also increases. What I actually need is to call psql copy with multiple csv file. I need to create the parallelization on the db, not on the openshift pod.
How can I do this? If this is not possible, what is the most optimum way to load multiple files at a time?

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

```
cat *.csv | psql -h $host -p $port -d $db -U $username -c "\copy \"$schema\".\"$table\" from STDIN with delimiter as ',' csv"
```

Comment: Hi Gerard,
Actually I need to upload n different files to n different db tables  in parallel fashion.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from starting multiple loads.  I know that with Oracle it was possible to make a database migration a lot faster.  But you should find out  after how many parallel sessions performance no longer increases.